# Adding Windows SharePoint Services users from local users on hyper V

Tags: security, sharepoint, hyper-v, user-management

I am running Windows SharePoint Services on a Hyper V server provided by my ISP. My WSS install is standalone and using SQL Express. When I go to add users to the site collection I see all users on the current Active Directory, including other customers of the ISP - obviously not what I want.

I'd like to be able to add local windows users to the machine and provide those users access to the WSS sites, can I do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add local users to WSS.

In addition, I would recomend trying to work with your ISP though to see if your VM can either be disjoined from their domain or have your own domain created and managed for you. Otherwise it may end up being very difficult to manage and could potentially be vulnerable to attacks from other machines/users that are trusted which you have no control over.

Answer (score 0):

There's a GUI way, but you can basically just type in MachineName\username for a local user, just as you'd type in DomainName\username for a domain user.

Comment: I thought as much but do I have to wait for WSS to crawl the local database of users like I would with MOSS and AD? Cheers Kara

Comment: I'd expect it to be a similar process, yeah.

Comment: Great! Any ideas on how I can group local users and have them only see local users in their group when inside WSS?

Comment: As in creating local groups on the server?  Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean about seeing other users.

Comment: In MOSs when you bring up the people picker dialog, it shows everyone, everything. I want to make it so local users in a group only see their local users in the group they are in. I hope that makes sense! :)

Comment: Gotcha!  I'm not sure you'd be able to trim that down without editing the site.  Deeper than I've delved, unfortunately.